# Preventing flat spot development on rim

Tags: wheels, rims

When hitting bumps, wheels sometimes develop flat spots. Can this be reduced by building wheels with higher spoke tension, or is this mainly result of strength of a rim?

When I say flat spot, I mean wheel radially going out of true, not small nicks on the edge of the rim.

Comment: Do you mean small, localized flat spots on the edge of the rim (where you hit the bump) or larger areas where the rim is no longer round (radial offset)?

Comment: If the the tire is briefly going flat so that the bump force is applied directly to the rim then you need to increase your tire pressure.

Comment: I am basically concerned with larger areas where rim is no longer round

Comment: Tires are at their maximum pressure

Comment: What kind of bike is this and what kind of terrain? I don't know any mountain bikers but I've never heard of wheels being knocked out of round on the road. If this is happening to you with any regularity at all (as in, more than once in your life), there's a good chance that you're riding too roughly.

Comment: How deep are your rims? I mean what height does the chamber between the spoke holes and the bed for the tube have? Do your rims even have such a chamber? If not, that's your problem: That chamber adds a lot to the structural strength of a rim. And the higher the chamber, the better.

Comment: Perhaps you should describe your rim.  Rims with fewer than 24 spokes are significantly weaker, and rims which attempt to be dramatically lighter than normal are likewise weaker.

Comment: The bike is workhorse, used for transport, heavily loaded, steel frame, rear ODL 130mm, 36 stainless steel double butted spokes, Remerx RMXL 712 dole wall with eyelets rim (622), Claris 2400 hub, tyres Duro Cordoba 42-622 @5.5 bar. It is driven all over and around town in city traffic. I try to avoid craks, pots, holes, steep pavements, but over the time due to the traffic and other conditions in it is unavoidable to get some share and hit them hard sometimes.

Comment: If you hit something so hard that the tire is fully compressed against the rim, you will usually get a pinch-flat, a "snake-bite" double-hole in the tube (or tire, if tubeless). Is that happening? I've never experienced pinch flats except on the hardest of hits (like, "glad I didn't fall off the bike" experiences) with tires at less than 4 bar, and even so my rims were/are perfectly round. At 5.5 bar (28mm tires) I've never gotten a pinch flat, which should mean the tire is not fully compressed and therefore still protecting the rim. Also, pictures might help if they show the issue.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, stronger wheels will be more resistant to damage and going out of true.

Wheel strength is a combination and balance of of rim strength, number and gauge of spokes, spoke tension and the quality of the build (spoke tension evenness etc.)

If you are denting your rims on bumps, or they are going out of true there are some things you should do before considering new wheels:

- Avoid hitting bumps, and use good technique of you have to ride over them. See recent question about this [Is it a good idea to lift the front wheel to go through small bumps?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/55608/24228).
- Tire pressure should be enough so that the rim edges are not hitting the road surface.
- Consider running larger tires, if you bike can accommodate them.

Comment: Thanks. Tires are as large as they can be and at their maximum pressure, roads that I travel and their quality are given. But if I understand your answer correctly going for higher tension on the spokes could improve situation.

Comment: @DavorinRuševljan Maybe. If your wheels are out of true or are not of great quality, trying to tighten them up if you don not have experience with wheel building can be tricky.